# Enabling asy-mode coloring inside a latex block

Tags: latex

I have started using [Asymptote](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/) for making diagrams in \LaTeX. Asymptote comes with its own Emacs mode for editing `.asy` files in which 
we typically write Asymptote code.

However, I often write a lot of asymptote code inline inside my Latex buffer.

For instance,

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[inline]{asymptote}
\begin{document}
Save this code as \verb=test.tex= and compile it with:
\begin{verbatim}
latex test
asy test-*.asy
latex test
\end{verbatim}
\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \begin{asy}
    size(350);

    real a=3;
    real b=4;
    real c=hypot(a,b);

    transform ta=shift(c,c)*rotate(-aCos(a/c))*scale(a/c)*shift(-c);
    transform tb=shift(0,c)*rotate(aCos(b/c))*scale(b/c);

    picture Pythagorean(int n) {
      picture pic;
      fill(pic,scale(c)*unitsquare,1/(n+1)*green+n/(n+1)*brown);
      if(n == 0) return pic;
      picture branch=Pythagorean(--n);
      add(pic,ta*branch);
      add(pic,tb*branch);
      return pic;
    }

    add(Pythagorean(12));
  \end{asy}
\end{figure}
The above code block should be high-lighted with fontlock of \verb=asy-mode=.
\end{document}
```

generate [this tree](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/gallery/) from the example list on the website.

How can I enable/activate the asymptote mode syntax highlighting (or more generally the full blown asy-mode itself) when the cursor (point) is within the code-block that starts and ends with `\begin{asy}....\end{asy}`

More generally, how do I activate a given syntax highlighting of mode X between 2 (pre-decided) tokens when we are within working in an Emacs buffer which has major mode Y

Comment: I've changed your code fragment into a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Hope that is okay for you.

Comment: IMHO the general way is to use [`mmm-mode`](https://github.com/purcell/mmm-mode). But your case seems to be more complicated. The package `asy-mode.el` tries to activate [`two-mode-mode`](https://www.welton.it/freesoftware/files/two-mode-mode.el) which seems to be out-dated and obsolete. I've tried it without luck. I've also tried to activate `mmm-mode` with `asy-mode`. But, `asy-mode` bases on `objc-mode` which in turn bases on `cc-mode` and there is an [open issue](https://github.com/purcell/mmm-mode/issues/55) with the combination of  `mmm-mode` and `cc-mode`.